# Migrating a huge oracle database to cassandra

Tags: oracle, cassandra, data-migration

We are currently having a `SAP ERP` system with backend `Oracle` database with closer to `1000` tables. We want to migrate all the tables to `cassandra` for data processing.

What are the available tools for this migration and which would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your reference: [pillar](https://github.com/inoio/sbt-pillar-plugin) for Cassandra migrations (sbt and Scala)

> This sbt plugin allows to run Cassandra schema/data migrations from
>   sbt (using pillar). For details on migration files check out the
>   pillar documentation. The cassandra connection configuration is not
>   based on pillar but we're using our own format (see Configuration).

or:

[How to Move Data from Relational Databases to DataStax Enterprise / Cassandra using Sqoop](http://www.datastax.com/2012/03/how-to-move-data-from-relational-databases-to-datastax-enterprise-cassandra-using-sqoop)